# Getting HTML elements as v-bind data

Tags: vue.js

I am adding Vue.js to an existing webpage with an HTML table. (I can't control the HTML, but can inject a link to my Vue file.)

I cannot insert dynamic JavaScript, but the data is already on the page. I hence want to give Vue the ability to read the data from the HTML.

The simplified table is like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>DOB</th>
      <th>Sex</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>01 Jan</td>
      <td>M</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>25 Dec</td>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to turn this into the equivalent of:

```
<some-component
    v-bind:data="[
        {'Name':'John', 'DOB': '01 Jan', 'Sex' : 'M'},
        {'Name':'Jane', 'DOB': '25 Dec', 'Sex' : 'F'}
    ]">
</some-component>
```

I can obviously loop through the table to create a JavaScript variable manually, but it seems very inefficient - can Vue read data from HTML like this?

Answer (score 0):

Vue has no built-in mechanism to build an object from arbitrary HMTL. (The virtual DOM works in the opposite way, building a virtual HTML structure from objects.)

In this specific case, it's not hard to create the object in plain JavaScript

```
var tableEl = document.querySelector("table");
var keys = Array.from(tableEl.tHead.rows[0].cells).map(el => el.textContent.trim());
var array = Array.from(tableEl.tBodies[0].rows).map(row => {
  var entry = {};
  keys.forEach((key, index) => {entry[key] = row.cells[index].textContent.trim();})
  return entry;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you can do it with vue :

First you need to create the component with the following template:

```
         var template = "
          <table>
            <thead>
               <th>Name</th><th>DOB</th><th>Sex</th>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              <tr v-for="obj in data" :key="obj.Name">
                  <td>{{obj["Name"]}}</td>
                  <td>{{obj["DOB"]}}</td>
                  <td>{{obj["Sex"]}}</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>"
```

then just pass the data you want to display on the component below as prop (bind)

run the following snippet :

```js
// the component
Vue.component('some-component',{  
          props : ['data'],
          template : '<table><thead><th>Name</th><th>DOB</th><th>Sex</th></thead><tbody><tr v-for="obj in data" :key="obj.Name"><td>{{obj["Name"]}}</td><td>{{obj["DOB"]}}</td><td>{{obj["Sex"]}}</td></tr></tbody></table>'
})
// the instance
new Vue({
   el : '#app'
})
```

```css
table,th,td {
   padding : 10px;
   border : 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <some-component  v-bind:data="[
            {'Name':'John', 'DOB': '01 Jan', 'Sex' : 'M'},
            {'Name':'Jane', 'DOB': '25 Dec', 'Sex' : 'F'},
            {'Name':'foo', 'DOB': '22 Dec', 'Sex' : 'M'},
            {'Name':'bar', 'DOB': '21 Dec', 'Sex' : 'M'}
             ]">
</some-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh sorry, the question is more about getting the data dynamically from the *existing* table in the HTML.